# react-router-dom redirect not redirecting to the component I want it to but it is redirecting to a different path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Versions

```
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-redux": "^7.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
```

I have an issue where my conditional `Redirect` component is not working as it should. Is it because it's outside of the `Switch` component. I want it to redirect to the `/error` route if apiError is true. The conditional works since I tested with just the `Error` component and not the error route. The `Redirect` component also works since the path does change but the component is not rendered.

```
render() {
    const { currentUser, isLoaded, apiError } = this.state;
    return ( 
      <Router>
        {currentUser ? (
          <div className='App'>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/title/:id' render={props => <ShowTitle {...props} /> } />
              <Route exact path='/shuffle' render={props => <Titles {...props} isLoaded={isLoaded} /> } />
              <Route exact path='/about' render={props => <About {...props} /> } />
              <Route exact path='/all-titles' render={props => <Titles {...props} isLoaded={isLoaded} /> } />
              <Route exact path='/error' render={props => <Error {...props} />} />
              <Route exact path='/' render={props => <Redirect to={'/' + currentUser.viewType} /> } />
              <Route exact path='/logout' component={Logout} />
              <Redirect to='/all-titles' />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        ) : apiError ? <Redirect to='/error' /> : (
          <Landing isLoaded={this.state.isLoaded}></Landing>
        )}
      </Router>
    );
```

Comment: Why do you want to implement the switch only when `currentUser` is true? What is `currentUser` reflects?

Comment: @BlackMath `currentUser` is either `null` or a user object so until the user is loaded in, the `Landing` component is rendered. If it's successful and a user is returned then everything in the `Switch` component can be access.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing a logical error with it.

```
<Route exact path='/error' render={props => <Error {...props} />} />
```

Doesn't exist when `apiError`.

This probably work for you:

```
render() {
    const { currentUser, isLoaded, apiError } = this.state;
    let route = (<Landing isLoaded={isLoaded} />);
    if (currentUser) {
      route = (
        <div className='App'>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/title/:id' render={props => <ShowTitle {...props} /> } />
            <Route exact path='/shuffle' render={props => <Titles {...props} isLoaded={isLoaded} /> } />
            <Route exact path='/about' render={props => <About {...props} /> } />
            <Route exact path='/all-titles' render={props => <Titles {...props} isLoaded={isLoaded} /> } />
            <Route exact path='/error' render={props => <Error {...props} />} />
            <Route exact path='/' render={props => <Redirect to={'/' + currentUser.viewType} /> } />
            <Route exact path='/logout' component={Logout} />
            <Redirect to='/all-titles' />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      );
    }
    if (apiError) {
      route = (
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/error' render={props => <Error {...props} />} />
        </Switch>
      );
    }
    return ( 
      <Router>
        {route}
      </Router>
    );
};
```

For better usage, I recommend to you declare all routes statically, on HOC module, then validate props and use `Redirect` component to navigate to other path.